# SQL stored procedure using two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created a database called stock trades and two tables (company data and stock_data) I want to create a procedure that will help me find stocks over 500K volume and in the technology sector. sector variable is in table company data and volume variable in stock_data) here is my code so far:

[stockcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFdXJ.png)

```
create procedure highvolumetechstock
as
select Volume
from stock_data
    INNER JOIN Companydata ON stock_data.Volume = Companydata.Sector
where Sector = 'Technology' and Volume > 500000

exec highvolumetechstock
```

Comment: What's the point of creating a procedure, while you can just run the SQL statement directly ?

Comment: need it specifically for a class haha

Comment: and how can we help you? like whats happening?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to declare in procedure in mysql. Please note that, as commented, using a procedure is does not make a lot of sense, as you could obtain the same result with a simple SQL query.

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE highvolumetechstock()
BEGIN 
    SELECT Volume
    FROM stock_data
        INNER JOIN Companydata ON stock_data.Volume = Companydata.Sector
    WHERE Sector = 'Technology' AND Volume > 500000
END //
delimiter ;
```

Then you execute the procedure with :

```
CALL highvolumetechstock();
```